# remove icons in header in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, home

please visit this : http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/

on above Ph : 0800, there is icon image [phone image ] after my wishlist, I want to remove that phone image.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an image.
there is this in your source:

```
 <span class="customer-service">Ph: 0800 844 866 <a style="background-color: orange; position: relative; left: 150px;" href="EMAIL REMOVED FOR SECURITY"> Email us </a></span>
```

Look for that text in your template files and remove it.
Enable [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/) and you will find the template you need to modify.

Comment: pleae help me , i really need your help now : check the site http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/ now, i added line <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header-phone')->toHtml‌​(); ?> in header.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/gy6TLyNq but email is not linking.

Comment: Actually the link works, but there is a div over it. The div with class `grid_24 header-bottom`. Try to re-position it so it won't go over your block

Comment: you are right, please help me where i have to place the line code.

Comment: Let's keep this website clean. Our discussion here has nothing to do with this question. I already identified the problem for you. Try to solve it. If I find something else I will post on the right question.

Comment: hi, right now some how the problem solved. finally using trail and error method, i placed code in somewhere and its working. 

Thanks a lot again.....

Answer (score 1):

That phone icon comes from the icon class that your using in the p tag by background url . So please remove that .